Footnotes are not copied as a block
Does anyone know why the WP post footnotes are in the postmeta table and not in the one where the articles (posts) are located?
This choice means that the copy-paste of the footnotes (edit side) does not work: the block copied to another page or article shows the empty footnotes.
Technically, what was the need to make this choice instead of putting all the content in the posts table?
Always technically, do you think it will be possible to foresee that the "copy" also takes the footnotes?

There were attempts to add footnotes support to core for several years, with several approaches being explored. It was decided to store them in post meta to make it easier to render the footnotes outside of the post content in templates. See: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/51201
